# slow SQL command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to take some data from one table (and expand some XML on the way) and put it in another table. As the source table can have thousands or records which caused a timeout I decided to do it in batches of 100 records. The code is run on a schedule so doing it in batches works ok for the customer. If I have say 200 records in the source database the sproc runs very fast but if there are thousands it takes several minutes. I'm guessing that the "TOP 100" only takes the top 100 after it has gone through all the records. I need to change the whole code and sproc at some point as it doesn't scale but for now is there a quick fix to make this run quicker ?

```
INSERT INTO [deviceManager].[TransactionLogStores] 
SELECT TOP 100 [EventId],
    [message].value('(/interface/mac)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS mac,
    [message].value('(/interface/device) [1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS device_type,
    [message].value('(/interface/id) [1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS device_id,
    [message].value('substring(string((/interface/id)[1]), 1, 6)', 'nvarchar(100)') AS store_id,
    [message].value('(/interface/terminal/unit)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS unit,
    [message].value('(/interface/terminal/trans/event)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS event_id,
    [message].value('(/interface/terminal/trans/data)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS event_data,
    [message].value('substring(string((/interface/terminal/trans/data)[1]), 9, 11)', 'nvarchar(100)') AS badge,
    [message].value('(/interface/terminal/trans/time)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS terminal_time,
    MessageRecievedAt_UTC AS db_time
FROM [deviceManager].[TransactionLog]
WHERE EventId > @EventId
--WHERE MessageRecievedAt_UTC > @StartTime AND MessageRecievedAt_UTC < @EndTime
ORDER BY terminal_time DESC
```

Comment: Is EventId indexed on TransactionLog table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the ORDER BY? The TOP shouldn't need to get the whole result set back to chop off the top 100 if the data isn't sorted. If you do need the order by, make sure you've got an index on terminal_time; if it's taking that long, you probably haven't.

Also, make sure you've got an index on EventID.

Comment: +1 for ORDER BY. Not sure if you can make an index on an XPath expression, though (Can you?).

Comment: @Tomalak Good point! I hadn't noticed it was an XPath expression, and not a standard column.

Retrocoder -- this will be why it's taking a surprisingly long time to select as the table gets bigger. Because the ORDER BY is an XPath expression, the server will have to evaluate the entire result set, including executing the XPath for every row, before it can sort the data (and thus figure out _which_ TOP 100 you want.)

If you can't remove the ORDER BY, can you use a real column in the table to sort by?

Comment: Obviously, you can have an XML index in SQL Server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx).

Comment: Cool! I don't think you could, the last time I looked, but I only poke around with the XML stuff in SQL Server every year or two. (I use XML a lot, and I use SQL a lot, but in separate arenas...)

So, yeah, drop the ORDER BY if you can, and then get some indexes on the items you're ordering by/filtering on, and life should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes on `EventId` (and `MessageRecievedAt_UTC`)?

Do `@EventId` and `@StartTime/@EndTime` have the same data type as the respective columns?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (correct me if I'm wrong and this is some other construct) `message.value()` is a UDF that's always taking the same inputs. You're calling that function about 10 times every N rows -- this is certainly going to be a performance burden. If this is a deterministic function (I hope it is) you could just cache the results of those various function calls into a temp table and the performance should improve significantly.

Failing that, it's probably the sorting that's taking the longest time. It has to get the full result set before it can decide how to sort. As Matt noted, an index could greatly speed this up.